# Html5 audio doesn't play in Cordova App

Tags: jquery, ios, html, cordova, audio

I'm working on a legacy codebase which is a jquery app running a skinned version of pacman. The background audio works fine but the sound effects do not. I suspect there is a special permission to put into config.xml but haven't been successful.

Can anyone point out why ios wouldn't be playing sound effects, even though the audio files are loaded from the same directory? Please let me know what other parts of code might be helpful.

Thank you very much.

Here's the config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="de.grammatidis.battle" version="1.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Battle</name>
    <description>Vorsicht, die rasenden Beißerchen haben es auf dich abgesehen! Flüchte so schnell du kannst mit dem Grammatidis-Männchen vor den wilden Zahngeistern und sammle dabei Punkte! 
    </description>
    <author email="kontakt@biloba-it.de" href="http://www.biloba-it.de">
        Biloba IT
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~1.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.1.0" />
</widget>
```

Here's the audio.js

```
var Sound = function(game) {
    this.files          = {}; 
    this.loaded         = {};
    this.paths          = {};
    this.loop           = {};
    this.playing        = [];
    this.stopped        = [];
    this.playingIndex   = {};
    this.game = game;
    this.volume = 1;
    this.disabled = game.getSetting("soundDisabled") == "true" ? true : false;
    this.multiple = ["snd_eat","snd_eatghost"];
    this.backgroundSounds = ["original","elektro","dance","rock","pop","kids"];
    this.interval       = {};
};

Sound.prototype.load = function(name, path, realload, callback) {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.load');
    var _self = this;

    //save the path
    this.paths[name] = path;

    if(_self.loaded[name] == true) {
        if(callback) callback();
    } else {
        if(realload) {
            //load the audio file
            _self.files[name] = new Media(path,
                function(){},
                function(){},
                function(status){
                    //check if done
                    if(status == 4 && _self.stopped.indexOf(name) == -1) {
                        if(_self.loop[name] == true) {
                            _self.files[name].play();
                        } else {
                            var i = _self.playing.indexOf(name);
                            if(i != -1) {
                                _self.playing.slice(i,1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            //set the loaded flag
            _self.loaded[name] = true;
            if(callback) callback();

        } else {            
            _self.loaded[name] = false;
            if(callback) callback();
        }
    }
};

Sound.prototype.toggleSound = function() {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.toggleSound');

    if(this.disabled) {
        this.enableSound();
    } else {
        this.disableSound();
    }
};

Sound.prototype.enableSound = function() {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.enableSound');

    this.disabled = false;
    this.game.saveSettings("soundDisabled", "false");
    if(this.game.getSetting("music") == "original") {
        this.play(this.game.getSetting("music"), false, 0.2);
    } else {
        this.play(this.game.getSetting("music"), true, 0.2);
    }
};

Sound.prototype.disableSound = function(callback) {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.disableSound');

    var _self = this;
    this.disabled = true;
    this.game.saveSettings("soundDisabled", "true");

    for (var i = 0; i < this.playing.length; i++) {
        _self.stop(this.playing[i]);
    }
    this.playing = [];
    if(callback) callback();
};

Sound.prototype.isDisabled = function() {
    return this.disabled;
};

Sound.prototype.isLoaded = function(name) {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.isLoaded');

    var _self = this;

    var i = _self.playingIndex[name];
    if(i === undefined || i == null) i = 1;
    _self.playingIndex[name] = i;

    return (_self.loaded[name] == true) || (_self.multiple.indexOf(name) != -1 && _self.loaded[name + "_" + i] == true);
};

Sound.prototype.play = function(name, loop, volume, callback) {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.play');

    var _self = this;

    function doPlay() {
        //remove from the stopped list
        var i = _self.stopped.indexOf(name);
        if(i != -1) {
            _self.stopped.slice(i,1);
        }

        //add to the playing list
        if(_self.playing.indexOf(name) == -1) _self.playing.push(name);

        //check if the sound can be played multiple times
        if(_self.multiple.indexOf(name) != -1) {
            var i = _self.playingIndex[name];
            if(i === undefined || i == null) i = 1;
            i++;
            if(i > 5) i = 1;
            _self.playingIndex[name] = i;
            name = name + "_" + i;
        }

        //set the volumen
        if(volume !== undefined) {
            _self.files[name].setVolume(volume);
        } else {
            _self.files[name].setVolume(_self.volume);
        }

        _self.files[name].play();
        _self.loop[name] = loop;

        if(loop) {
            var duration = _self.files[name].getDuration();
            if(duration != -1) {
                _self.interval[name] = setInterval(function(){
                    _self.files[name].play();
                }, (duration+10) * 1000);
            }
        }
    }

    var blnPlay = true;
    if(Platform.isApp() && this.isBackgroundSound(name) == false) blnPlay = false;

    if(this.disabled == false && blnPlay == true) {
        if(_self.isLoaded(name)) {
            doPlay();
            if(callback) callback();
        } else {
            _self.load(name, _self.paths[name], true, function(){
                doPlay();
                if(callback) callback();
            });
        }
    } else {
        if(callback) callback();
    }
};

Sound.prototype.stop = function(name) {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.stop');

    if(this.files[name] !== undefined) {
        this.stopped.push(name);
        if(this.interval[name] !== undefined){
            clearInterval(this.interval[name]);
        }
        this.files[name].stop();
    }
};

Sound.prototype.pause = function() {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.pause');

    for (var i = 0; i < playing.length; i++) {
        this.files[playing[i]].pause();
    }
};

Sound.prototype.resume = function() {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.resume');

    for (var i = 0; i < playing.length; i++) {
        this.files[playing[i]].play();
    }        
};

Sound.prototype.isBackgroundSound = function(snd) {
    console.log('Sound.prototype.isBackgroundSound');

    return (this.backgroundSounds.indexOf(snd) != -1);
};
```

Comment: The code where you actually try to play the audio would be useful...  There are a several ways to play audio in Cordova.  Audio tag, Media plugin, other plugins, etc...  Which method are you using to try to play the audio?


Also what version of Cordova are you using?  Do you have a CSP setup in the index.html?

Comment: Cheers Brad, the codebase is pretty convoluted but I'll paste the audio.js above. Looks like it's using functions from the Media plugin. Doesn't look like a CSP is set in the index. Got audio working through native javascript calls but it's not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of code.  The media plug is definitely very finicky (and buggy) in my experience.  I use it a lot.  Can you verify that you can load and play one file by just running the basic example like this:

```
var player = new Media(path,   
     function playSuccess() { 
        console.log("success");
        player.release();
     },
     function playError(err) {
        console.log("uh oh: " + err.code);
     });
player.play();
```

I do notice you are not releasing the resources which may be an issue with a long running game.

Are you trying to replay / loop the sounds by detecting the stop in the status function? I think you might want to do that from the success function by calling play again (possibly wrapped in a setTimeout(xx.play,0)).  I haven't tried calling play from within those callbacks before.

Comment: Hi, thanks Brad.. the new Media() function does work, as does new Audio(). seems like the difference is that Media has callback integrated. I'll play around with the how to stop a sound.. probably put all the sounds on the root scope so that the right function call can play/pause the sounds. Thanks for the help!